# Undefined property: stdClass::$category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a json file that looks like this

```
{
    "Product_1": {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "category": "Yellow"
    },
    "Product_2": {
        "name": "Product 2",
        "category": "Blue"
    },
    "Product_3": {
        "name": "Product 3",
        "category": "Yellow"
    }
}
```

I need to do a bulk change on all my categories if that category is yellow. When I try to do it I get this error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$category
```

Here is my code

```
$products = Product::all();

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $json = file_get_contents(storage_path("products/$product->id/products.json"));
    $productJson = json_decode($json);

    if($productJson->category == 'Yellow')
    {
        $productJson->category = 'Green';
        file_put_contents(storage_path("products/$product->id/products.json"), json_encode($productJson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
}
```

I get this when I `dd($productJson)`

```
{
  +"name": "Product 1"
  +"category": "Yellow"
}
```

and if I `var_dump($productJson)` I get my json output but then I also get the error afterwards.

Comment: What do you see if you dump($productJson) before checking if ($productJson->category)? Does the variable contain the data you would expect? Which specific record does it fail on? Does that record have a category?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper - I've updated my question to have my output

Comment: try to access like this: ```$productJson['category']```

Comment: @hmrneves - I get this error ` Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
`

Comment: The output of dd() shows a category as expected. That is outputting the first record and stopping. If you switch to dump(), you should see all that it processes and lastly the one which causes the error. Does it get past the first record, and if so does the record it fails on have a category? You may want to add an if(isset($productJson->category)) to ensure it is set on each individual record.